# What is wrong with my jQuery Plugin's syntax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am currently studying how to create jQuery plugins, and have created the code below. I've added my own function and extended the options after adding defaults for my plugin, but nothing is happening. I even added an alert - but it isn't showing either.

Here is my code so far:

```
(function($){  

    // Extend the Jquery Object with the Myedit Function
    jQuery.fn.Myedit = function(options) {  

        // Default options
        var defaults = {  
            width: 250,  
            height: 20,  
            url: "",  
            data: {},  
            buttons: false  
        };

        // Extend the options with the onse the user provided
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

        return this.each(function() {  
            var object = $(this);

            $(object).live('click', function () {
                var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'name': $(this).attr('name'), 'value': $(this).html()});
                $(this).parent().append(input);
                $(this).remove();
                input.focus();
            });

            $(object).live('blur', function () {
                $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $(this).hide();
        });  
    };  
    //return alert(object);
})(jQuery);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ypBh/)**

This is just a pointer, you should look more on how to create a [jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

```
(function($){  

     // Extend the Jquery Object with the Myedit Function
     jQuery.fn.Myedit = function(options) {  

          // Default options
          var defaults = {  
               width: 250,  
               height: 20,  
               url: "",  
               data: {},  
               buttons: false  
          };

          // Extend the options with the onse the user provided
          var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

           return this.each(function() {  

            var object = $(this);
               var span = 'span[name=' + object.attr('name') + ']';
               var input = 'input[name=' + object.attr('name') + ']';

            $(document).on('click',span ,function () {
                var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'name': $(this).attr('name'), 'value': $(this).html()});
                $(this).parent().append(input);
                $(this).remove();
                input.focus();
            });

            $(document).on('blur',input, function () {
                $(this).parent().append($('<span />',{name:object.attr('name')}).html($(this).val()));
                $(this).remove();
            });

          });  
     };  
     //return alert(object);
})(jQuery);
$('span').Myedit();
```

Couple of things:-

- You were hiding the element in the end so it was not at all visible.
- You are dynamically creating the element on different action so binding just a click event is not enough you need to use Event Delegation using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). so that dynamically created elements have the event delegated from its parent withouth having to bind them again.

Comment: No problem.. Glad it gave you some pointers or information.. :)